# Convert varchar to timestamp in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have few columns in a snowflake table which has date time stored in the format
2022-04-27T10:38:21.3000000+1000 as VARCHAR.

I would want to convert it as proper Timestamp object. I tried using below

TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-04-27T10:38:21.3000000+1000')

It is throwing error as not recognized format. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the input format for your date/time string as per the doc

Try this:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-04-27T10:38:21.3000000+1000', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FFTZHTZM');
```